# How to login into battle.net if I forgot my logs?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I haven't played World of Warcraft for 2 years, I can't remember my email, password, gamertag or phone number. There used to be a number to call. Now there's no number and I've scoured the website looking for an answer.

What can I do to access my account ?

Answer (score 5):

You can open up a ticket [at this convenient and easy-to-use form](https://us.battle.net/support/en/help/). After choosing the proper options, you are given several contact options:

- Submit a ticket - Available 24/7 - [Currently a higher-than-normal response time](https://us.battle.net/support/en/blog/16893473/)
- Call Blizzard support - Available 10AM to 6PM PST
- Live chat support - Available 10AM to 6PM PST

By filling out the form during open hours, you are free to contact them however you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Billing, Account Services & Technical Support
Hours: 7 AM to 8 PM Pacific Time

Phone: 1-800-592-5499
Australia: 1-800-041-378
New Zealand: 0-800-452-520
Chile: 1230-020-5554
Mexico: 001-888-578-762
Argentina: 0800-333-0778
Brazil: 0-800-892-1630

Try that ?

Comment: Waow there's one for Argentina, lol.

Comment: I was surprised to see them have a number for brazil ..

Comment: Guess we all learned something new today huh ? :)